# How to quantify temporal overlap of species abundance?

Tags: time-series, ecology, spatio-temporal, overlapping-data

I want to compare the extent of overlap of species abundances in the following two secanrios. In the first scenario, species barely overlap so the index or overlap value should be zero. in the second case species fairly overlap in their abundances. To be clear, I have species abundance sampled each month.

I found [Piyanka's index (from Gotelli 2000)](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Engotelli/EcoSim/Niche%20Overlap%20Tutorial.html) to be one such index that estimates the extent of overlap. However, on closer reading, I find that takes the resource utilization matrix as input and returns the average pairwise Pianka's niche overlap index averaged over each species pair as so:

`O_jk = O_kj = sum(p_ij*p_jk) / sqrt(sum((p_ij)^2)sum((p_jk)^2))`

I am not sure if I can use it to compute the overlap of species abundance distributions alone. I am wondering are there any other indices that I can use to do a similar computation? Is there a statistical route that I can take to capture a breath of overlap?

Note: My data has absolute abundance. The graph is only for representation

Calling on my fellow ecologists for help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The charts make me think the Wasserstein distance could be a good solution